# C# Spam Filter suggestions

Tags: c#, database, filter, spam

Any idea (example) of spam filter implementation in C#? I would like to use a database to store unwanted words, to train my spam filter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patterns are more important than words (barring "#FF0000", you can be pretty much 100% confident that anything sent as an HTML mail will "#FF0000" in it is not worth reading). Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering and the references it has for one approach (IIRC, one of the first experiments with technique found that after training the filter, "#FF0000" was the expression most likely to indicate Spam, see I told you so).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out Paul Graham spam filtering article You can also have a look at [C# implementation of spam filter using Naive Bayes Classifier](http://raza-rizvi.blogspot.com/2010/06/text-classifier-using-naive-bayes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trivial hand-made spam filter based on word blacklist: [LINQ Query for Blacklist-Based Spam Filter](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=hints/linq-query-blacklist-spam-filter)

This solution is applicable when you don't find motivation to add libraries or complicated custom solution.